# Creating complicated files from a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

## Problem:

So I have a python program that sets up template python projects for a user when run. (e.g. a directory with a setup.py file, a json file, etc.). And I'm hitting a bit of a wall when trying to create those files themselves.

###### A very basic template project might look like this:

```
helloworld/
│
├── .gitignore
├── helloworld.py
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── tests.py
```

### What I've thought of:

#### Idea 1:

1. I've thought of just writing the template files, saving them in a folder and then just copying them to the new directory.

```
from shutil import copyfile
copyfile(src, dst)
```

#### Problem with this:

The problem with this, is that certain metadata such as the program name, version, requirements, etc. need to be dynamic, and I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

#### Idea 2:

2. The other option that I can think of, is to manually type the files into the program and then appending it to a blank file with a tedious and accident-prone, line-by-line appending process.

```
with open('file.json', w) as f:
    f.write('''
{
  "manifest_version": v1.0,
  "name": "example",
}
''')
```

Using this method, I could use f strings to insert dynamic data.

```
with open('file.json', w) as f:
    f.write(f'''
{
  "version": "{version}",
  "name": "{name}",
}
''')
```

#### Problem with this:

But this just seems like bad practice, not to mention tedious. Especially as some of these templates could get quite big with files such as setup.py, setup.cfg, __init__.py, MANIFEST, .gitignore, etc.

##### Is there a better way to write complicated files from python?

Comment: You can use the built-in JSON library to automatically export `dict` objects to valid JSON, and vice versa. Have you looked into that?

Comment: Thanks for that tip, I'll definitely try that out, but what about other file types? (.cfg, .py, .yml, .MD, .in, etc)

Comment: It really isn't clear what you mean at all. How do you *expet* Python to just create the files with the format you want, magically?

Comment: As an aside, the following project might be something you want to take a look at: https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.2/README.html

Comment: @God-status I misunderstood the scope of your project. There are libraries out there that do this kind of thing, apparently; looks like [Jinja](https://zetcode.com/python/jinja/) might be a good place to start and see if that's along the lines of what you need.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm not looking for a magical solution, I'm just wondering if there's a better way to write data to files, than  manually, line-by-line (and with dynamic data).

Comment: @RandomDavis That looks like a good place to start, thank you.

Comment: @God-status again, I don't know exactly what you mean by "manually line by line". As opposed to what? In any case, there are various libraries out there for templeting and, as the one I pointed out, for templeting projects! Probably better to see if one of those works for you than trying to re-invent the wheel

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga To clarify, by line-by-line, I mean use the built in open() function. This is fine for .txt and LOG files, but it gets rather hard to format, when handling more complex files with more complex syntax. I will be sure to check out the link you provided, thank you.